# Get current track playing on control center iOS

Tags: ios, mpnowplayinginfocenter, control-center

I'm looking to get the current track playing on iOS whatever the app which is playing the track. I mean, for example, if I use SoundCloud or Spotify on my phone, the player on control center is the same, so I think it's possible to get the current track name.

However I don't know how to do this, maybe someone could help me ?

Answer (score 6):

Frustratingly you can only get the details of the songs playing on the Music (iPod) app:

```
// Print the title of the currently playing song.
NSLog(@"%@", [[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]);
```

To get the details of songs from other apps you *should* be able to call:

```
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] nowPlayingInfo]
```

but it always returns `nil`.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: NFI, I wrote this 3 years ago, you'll have to test it for yourself :p