# Audio Information of Current Track iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

Let's say a track is playing (through any app), and I want to get the song information, such as the name. It shows up on your screen when you lock the phone, along with the album cover. How can I get that information using swift?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515633/get-current-track-playing-on-control-center-ios, the answer is not in swift but Objective-C. Check doc here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is example function to get audio Info:

```
import MediaPlayer

var url:NSURL!
let audioInfo = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()
var nowPlayingInfo:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [:]

func fetchMP3Info() {

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)  //this will be your audio source 
    println(url.path!)

    let metadataList = playerItem.asset.metadata as! [AVMetadataItem]
    for item in metadataList {
        if item.commonKey != nil && item.value != nil {
            if item.commonKey  == "title" {
                println(item.stringValue)
                nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = item.stringValue
            }
            if item.commonKey   == "type" {
                println(item.stringValue)
                nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyGenre] = item.stringValue
            }
            if item.commonKey  == "albumName" {
                println(item.stringValue)
                nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] = item.stringValue
            }
            if item.commonKey   == "artist" {
                println(item.stringValue)
                nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = item.stringValue
            }
            if item.commonKey  == "artwork" {
                if let image = UIImage(data: item.value as! NSData) {
                    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)
                    println(image.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    audioInfo.nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo

}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Any other issues now?

Comment: On this line: let metadataList = playerItem.asset.metadata as! [AVMetadataItem], I"m getting the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Any tips? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Does this capture the title/artist/etc. on any app playing a song?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. You are merely setting the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, while the question is asking if you can access the data set by other apps. I am looking for that answer as well - it seems that its not possible to access the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` information set by another app - always returns nil.